# Sidebar by Category Conditional Statement not functioning

Tags: categories, sidebar, conditional-tags

I have two categories for my posts, "event" and "long-term-leasing." I have sidebar-events.php and sidebar-long-term.php. I wrote a conditional statement in single.php, but when I view a post it only shows me the generic sidebar. I did a copy/paste of the categories to avoid typos. Where is my mistake?

```
    <?php
    if (is_category("event")) {
        get_sidebar('events');
    } elseif (is_category('long-term-leasing')) {
        get_sidebar('long-term');
    } else {
        get_sidebar();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure they are terms in the category taxonomy? If so, maybe you need to reset the main WordPress query - add `wp_reset_query();` before the `if` block starts.

Comment: They are categories. I cut and pasted from the category dashboard to ensure accuracy. I tried your suggestion, but sadly there was no change.

Comment: Ah, "in `single.php`". That's why the `is_category()` fails. Try `in_category()`. But I assume the post would only be in one of those categories?

Comment: in_category() worked! That one letter change just salvaged my weekend.  Sally CJ,  I shall also worship you.

Comment: I would like to post the corrected code here, but I can't figure out how to properly wrap the code.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and for posting code in comments, just wrap the code with backticks - i.e. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `has_category`, instead; `is_category` is used for archive pages, not single posts.

Comment: that was me struggling to post the updated code. (It's my first day using the forum.) Is there an advantage to using has_category() vs in_category()?

Comment: They both do the same thing. Not sure if there's any difference performance wise. `in_category` is the older version of `has_category`, it is still supported though and it uses `has_category` behind the scenes.

Comment: @marilynn, `in_category()` and `has_category()` both use (or are wrappers for) [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/). But unlike `has_category()`, `in_category()` requires the category name/ID/slug (or array of said) which is the first parameter, be specified at all times - if `has_category()` is called without any parameters, then you're basically checking if the current post has *any* categories. So if you call `in_category()` without the first parameter, then `false` is returned all the times, despite the post has categories. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

For all who are struggling, here is what worked for me:

```
<?php
if (in_category("event")) {
    get_sidebar('events');
} elseif (in_category('long-term-leasing')) {
    get_sidebar('long-term');
} else {
    get_sidebar();
}
```

?>